# Show that $R=\{\frac{m}{5^n} \mid m \in \Bbb Z, n \in \Bbb N\}$ is a subring of $\Bbb Q$. What are the units of $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Show that $R=\{\frac{m}{5^n} \mid m \in \Bbb Z, n \in \Bbb N\}$ is a subring of $\Bbb Q$. What are the units of $R$?

Let $x,y \in R$, then $x-y=\dfrac{a}{5^k}- \dfrac{b}{5^t}=\dfrac{5^ka-5^tb}{5^{k+t}} \in R$.

If $r \in \Bbb Q$, then $r=\dfrac{q}{p}$ for coprime $q,p$. Now for $x \in R$ we have $rx=\dfrac{q}{p} \cdot \dfrac{m}{5^n}=\dfrac{q\cdot m}{p\cdot5^n} \in R$.

So $R$ is a subring of $\Bbb Q$.

How can I find the units of $R$?

Comment: Suppose that $\frac{m}{5^n}$ is an element of $R$, and there is some element of $R$ $\frac{a}{5^b}$ such that $\frac{m}{5^n}\frac{a}{5^b} = 1$.  What does this equation tell you about $m$?

Comment: $R=\mathbb Z[\frac15]$, the smallest subring of $\mathbb Q$ that contains $\frac15$.

Comment: For the second part of the subring test, shouldn't $r\in R$ instead of $r\in\mathbb{Q}$? If not, how does it follow that the product is again in $R$ if $p\neq5^n$ for some $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ring is $S^{-1}Z$, where $S=\{1,5,5^2,...\}$. Hence is it a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$.
Now to find out the units, $\frac{a}{5^n} \frac{b}{5^m}=1 \iff ab=5^{n+m}$. So if you assume $a,5$ to be coprime then $5^{n+m}|b$ hence you get an equation $ac=1, c\in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence $a=1, -1$. Note that in this calculation an implicit assumption is that $m,n\geq 0$ and $(a,5)=1$. This choice can only be made if the element is not already an integer with the numerator divisible by $5^k$ for some $k\geq 0$ to begin with. It is easy to check in that case the only choice of units are $5^k, -5^k$ for $k \geq 0$. So the set of units you get is $\{5^k : k\in \mathbb{Z}\} \cup \{-5^k: k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.